# image selector by tag name / loading image into the void?

Tags: jquery, image, load

I've included code in my project I don't understand.

```
// where dImage is an existing image entity on my page
$("<img>").attr("src", $(dImage).attr("src")).load(function() {
```

1) what does `$("<img>")` mean? I would assume it means all image entities in the DOM, but when i tried to `$("<img>").attr("woah","baby");` and then inspect the dom, there's no trace of my custom attribute. why?

2) why is this value `undefined` in load callback? `$("<img>").attr("src"); = undefined`.

3) what would this code be expected to do?

Insight greatly appreciated. What is the use of this statement?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and instead of trying to figure things out without any sort of background, you need to educate yourself on the basics.  I highly recommend the articles from Mozilla's MDN.  Check these out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

After that, you should read more into the basics of jQuery DOM manipulation:

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: been writing javascript for 16 and some years now. at times i get stuck anyway. your reply is appreciated just the same! mange tak!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. `$('<img>')` creates a new image element, which will get the `src` obtained from the `dImage` element. For *"all image entities in the DOM"*, you'd do `$('img')`, just like a CSS selector.

2) Which value? `$("<img>").attr("src"); = undefined.` is invalid code. If you actually mean the `src` of `$("<img>")`, then again it's because `$("<img>")` creates a new `img` element.

3) Create a new image, assign the `src`, and attach a `load` event handler that is invoked when the image is finished loading.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks! 1)/2) makes perfect sense, but I'm still very confused, the new image is nowhere in the dom visible or in generated source/firebug? (i'm not removing it later). also tried alerting this in the callback: alert(" this width:"+this.width + " this width:"+this.attr("src")); and the result is that width is 890px while attr throws an error. What is "this"? why wouldn't it be an object/entity that i can access attr's of?

Comment: Have you added it to the DOM? `var img = $("<img>").attr("src", $(dImage).attr("src"));  img.appendTo('body');` And if `this.attr(...` is in the callback, then `this` is the native DOM element, and it doesn't have an `.attr` method. That's a jQuery method, so you'd need `$(this).attr("src")`, or just `this.src`.

Comment: yes! it's not added to the dom. i think i get it now; the load event is simply there to ensure my image is loaded before i try to access the image's properties for animation. thanks!